# Vue js 2 radio inputs not retaining their selection

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a multi-step form with Vue v2 and the radio inputs are not retaining their selected values well going back and forth between steps. Vue v1 handles this fine. I could just use v1 but would like to stay on v2 if possible.

```
v1: http://codepen.io/anthonyholmes/pen/PpYvNB

v2: http://codepen.io/anthonyholmes/pen/qrWvaM
```

Comment: I had just tried your link and it works as you described it, i.e. the values are retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `name` or `id` of input fields are conflicting, due to which this issue is happening, I have removed those and this works fine. see the [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmYJoB)

Just use:

```
<label :for="choice.value">
    <input type="radio" :value="choice.val" v-model="questions[index].responses" /> {{ choice.text }}
</label>
```

Comment: Removing the `name` attribute worked perfectly! Thank you